# jquery call after success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling jquery ajax call,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: formLink,
    cache: false,
    data: ......,
    success : function(responseHTML) {
        $(".abc").html(responseHTML);
    }
});
```

Now in ".abc", lets say,

```
<html>
..............
</html>
<script>
alert("11"); //Not getting this alert
</script>
```

even tried with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alert("11");
});
```

Not able to get alert even after the success, Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly does `responseHTML` contain?

Comment: How is the browser supposed to know what sort of script you're using without specifying that its 'text/javascript'? Empty script tags don't say much...

Comment: Not only that but if you drop $(document).ready(function() { //dosomething }); into the page AFTER the document has loaded then how would the document ready event fire?

Comment: @MoarCodePlz: OK, for your textbook record, I have 'text/javascript'

Comment: @Dogbert: Its the response Object that comes from Spring MVC Controller

Comment: @Max: You're passing an object to `.html()`? Not a string? Could you do a `console.log(responseHTML)` and show us the output?

Comment: @Max If you're going to put code snippets in a question then please make sure they are concise and correct. One of the best ways for people to help you is by spotting errors in your syntax, which is not possible to do when you're snippeting out near pseudo-code.

Comment: Sorry for that, Well I am actually using Spring tiles, So instead of making example complex and just narrated the flow

Comment: and I am sure that there is nothing wrong in passing the parameters

Comment: what do you get in firebug console?

Comment: I would typically write my AJAX back to something with an ID.  So I would use and expect to see $("#abc").html(responseHTML); not .abc  That might not matter, but I thought I would throw it into the mix.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz The `text/javascript` is no longer needed in `<script>` tags in HTML5.  Plus, what other kinds of scripts can be run by the browser anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the doctype is not of html5  then you will need the type attribute on the script tag

oh.. and i hope you are not returning `<html>` tag in the response - only return a fraction of the html you need.

and if you can - return it with attributes that can be analyzed at the success call and init your js function from there

also remove the $(document).ready this event happened long before your ajax call, and will not happen again when you refresh a part of the page

Comment: I have that, sorry forgot to mention in the above example

Comment: yes you are right I am using JSP but My problem is after loading the page I need to call a function with parameters in it. So I can't call the function after :success in the script itself.

Comment: at the success of the ajax call set $(".abc").html(responseHTML); and then parse the html you have got, get the data you need from it and call your JS funciton, and if the function is needed to format the html, then just put it in a hidden div(or offset it or something) and then display it after you finish

Comment: sorry, let me give you an example, First I call a function it is having the jquery ajax call, this will get the response and the response contains the jsp model. Now in that response I have the function to call

Comment: it contains the raw body of the JS function? does it return only a function? or also html? you can always include the functions on the page and just return in an attribute the name of the function to call on the returned html

Comment: Ok, Finally I found the solution. I have another tile defined inside the rendered response and it is stopping the script to call. I corrected it, and working fine now, Thanks guys for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dataType:"html" to your ajax params.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
<script>
    alert("11"); //Not getting this alert
</script>
```

With

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        alert('11');
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: one question, if my response object contains the complete html content and in the content if I have any function to call, can I call that

Comment: I didn't want to repeat what others have said, but you shouldn't be returning an entire < h t m l > tag. Just return the contents that you intend to insert into whatever has the 'abc' class.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Add the whole view and method the ajax method is calling (obfuscating any sensitive data or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure it will work, but worth giving it a shot:

You can try returning your javascript code in a function, once the '.abc' html has been seen, call your return function name.